# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. Did I lost my Wordpress data?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, xampp

It was suggested to me, as a better option, to create a Wordpress website on my computer with Xampp and latter, when finished, migrate it to an online server.

I have been working on the website in the last few weeks and it was practically finished (a lot of content, text, etc). Xampp has been working fine and suddenly, today, it gives me the following error:

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

And I'm afraid I might had lost all the data because, unfortunately, I don’t have any backup (I know my fault).

I know that there are other similar questions, but I have tried some suggested solutions without success. I already changed the Port 3306 to 3307 (add it to the firewall), delete the file `ibdata1`, then also `ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1`… and the same error continues.

The **error** is:

```
22:50:25  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
22:50:25  [main]    Windows Version:  Home  64-bit
22:50:25  [main]    XAMPP Version: 7.3.10
22:50:25  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.4  [ Compiled: Jun 5th 2019 ]
22:50:25  [main]    Running with Administrator rights - good!
22:50:25  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
22:50:25  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
22:50:25  [main]    All prerequisites found
22:50:25  [main]    Initializing Modules
22:50:25  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
22:50:25  [main]    Control Panel Ready
22:51:12  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
22:51:12  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
22:51:14  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
22:51:14  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
22:51:14  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
22:51:14  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
22:51:14  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
22:51:14  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
22:51:14  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
22:51:14  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

If I put back the original `ibdata1`, the **log file** shows:

```
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=7] log sequence number 453813 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114052.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=2] log sequence number 94797887 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114052.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=4] log sequence number 99143814 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114052.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=11] log sequence number 459877 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114052.

***... lot of this...***

2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-12 23:15:41 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=9] log sequence number 445017 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114052.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

***... lot of this...***

2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 114043; transaction id 63055
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=243] log sequence number 94797887 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 114052.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200212 23:15:41
2020-02-12 23:15:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

If I delete `ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1` the **log file** shows:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 113917; transaction id 9
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200212 22:51:12
2020-02-12 22:51:12 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

It seems that the database is corrupted and I suspect a Windows update over night.

Please, help me at least to recover the text I had on the website. **Is there is any possibility to recover the data introduced in Wordpress**?

**-----------EDIT:**
After some trial and error **I was able to recover my data!**

Some of my files in mysql/data were corrupted. So, I managed to recover my data as follows:

1. I deleted all the files in mysql/data with exception of my database folder;
2. I copied the data in mysql/backup to mysql/data;
3. I replaced the ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 by the original ones.

I hope this information can help someone else.

Comment: Deleting files and expecting it to work is not a great plan. Did you back those up first? The `ibdata` files is where the actual data lives most of the time if using InnoDB, which is what you should be using.

Comment: Dear tadman, I saved a copy of ibdata before deleting it from C:\xampp\mysql\data. It was one of the suggested solutions I found online. However, I have no success putting it back. Do you think it is possible to recover some data with the original ibdata files?

Comment: If you have a complete backup of *all* the files in their original state *and* the same version of XMPP then it may be possible to transplant those onto another copy and restore, but this can be tricky. The best option is to have a dump produced with `mysqldump`. Everything else is degrees of viable.